# Need to create custom s3KeySensor

Tags: airflow

I'm using [airflow_docker](https://github.com/airflowdocker/airflow-docker) and it seems it does not come with an [s3KeySensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.5/_modules/airflow/sensors/s3_key_sensor.html#S3KeySensor.poke). It does come with a [Sensor](https://github.com/airflowdocker/airflow-docker/blob/master/src/airflow_docker/operator.py#L435) Class. How can I create my own custom s3KeySensor? Do I just have to inherit from Sensor and overwrite the poke method? Can I literally just copy the source code from the s3KeySensor? Here's the source code for the [s3KeySensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.5/_modules/airflow/sensors/s3_key_sensor.html#S3KeySensor.poke)

The reason I am using airflow docker is that it can run in a container and I can pass in aws role creds to the task container so that it has the proper and exact permissions to do an action other than using the worker container's role permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [upgrading](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/upgrading-to-2.html) to the latest version Airflow or at least start at [Airflow 2.0](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/index.html).

In Airflow 2.0, a majority of the operators, sensors, and hooks that are not considered core functionality are categorized and separated into providers. Amazon has a provider, [apache-airflow-providers-amazon](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/index.html), that includes the [S3KeySensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/sensors/s3_key/index.html).

You can also install backport providers so the one you would need is [apache-airflow-backport-providers-amazon](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-amazon/) if you want to stay on Airflow 1.10.5 (based on the links you sent).